# How to have only one input selected in a tr?

Tags: jquery

Here's an fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/YxU2H/9/
I'm trying to just have one checkbox or one radio button selected in the row. What I've tried doesnt work:

```
function selectedBox() {
      var bothChecked = false;
      var row = $(this).closest('tr');

      var isCboxChecked = $('row', '#cbox').is(':checked');
      var isRadChecked = $('row', '#rad').is(':checked');

      //var isCboxChecked = $('#cbox').is(':checked'); //true or false
      //var isRadChecked = $('#rad').is(':checked');

      if (first == second) {
          bothChecked = true;
          //keep checkbox selected but deselect radio button
      }
      if (bothChecked == true) {
          $('#cbox').attr('checked', false);
      }
      else {
          $('#cbox').attr('checked', true);
      }
  } //);
```

Then I just added an onclick="selectedBox();" to the checkboxes and buttons. Checkboxes had a id of cbox, and radio buttons had rad

Comment: There are a couple of issues with the HTML - IDs need to be unique, use classes for the checkboxes and radio buttons. Also all the checkboxes and radio buttons seemed to be wrapped in a `<label>` tag for some reason. That's causing selector issues as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put these two functions within `document.ready` block

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked') {
        var chk = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
        if (chk.length > 0) {
            $(chk).removeAttr('checked');
        }
    }
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked') {
        var rad= $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="radio"]:checked');
        if (rad.length > 0) {
            $(rad).removeAttr('checked');
        }
    }
});
```

Both monitor each others, so you will get your functionality. try it, worked for me. I have updated your fiddle. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/YxU2H/20/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$('#cbox').attr('checked', false);` try

```
  if (bothChecked == true) {
      $('#cbox').removeAttr('checked');
  }
  else {
      $('#cbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
  }
```

**Edit**

The complete solution would be like this

```
$("input:checkbox, input:radio").click(function(e) {

    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

    var chkBox = $(row).find(":checkbox");
    var rdBtn = $(row).find(":radio");

    if ($(chkBox).is(":checked") & $(rdBtn).is(":checked")) { 
      $(chkBox).removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

I put it on here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YxU2H/24/)

Comment: fiddle that pls, to double check it's functionality.